# Returning AWS EC2 availability_zone attribute using boto3 Python SDK

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to return information about all of the `EC2` instances in an `AWS` account using `boto3` `API` calls in `Python`, but I cannot get the `availability_zone` resource to display.

For instance, when I can iterate over all of my `EC2` instances successfully using this code:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

output = defaultdict()

for instance in ec2.instances.all()
    for iface in instance.network_interfaces:
        output[instance.id] = {
            'Instance ID': instance.id,
            'Subnet ID': iface.subnet_id
        }
```

I am leaving out the rest of the code, but the above works and outputs the values of those resources which I then put into a `csv` file using `Pandas` `.to_csv`.

When I try to add the following as a value in the `Python` `dictionary`:

```
'Availability Zone': instance.availability_zone
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ec2.Instance' object has no attribute 'availability_zone'
```

That's the expected behavior. I then try the following instead:

```
'Availability Zone': iface.availability_zone
```

This runs with error, but the output is null. There simple isn't anything in the `csv` file.

I looked at the `boto3` [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=availability%20zone#networkinterface), and `availability_zone` is an available resource attribute under the `NetworkInterface` resource, just like `subnet_id`, which I am using and is working.

What am I missing here? Can anyone point me in the right direction or let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @aws_apprentice, thanks for the reply. I think I am calling NetworkInterface by using iface.availability_zone. That is successfully returning the subnet_id attribute when called. When I call iface.availability_zone, i don't get any errors, it just returns null.

Comment: Try using the AWS CLI (or my favorite tool, the [`aws-shell`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-shell)), to explore interactively. If you're using the shell, run the command `ec2 describe-network-interfaces`. Do you see `AvailabilityZone` in that output? When I run the command, I see a zone associated with each interface, as expected. If it works here, it ought to work in your code as well.

Comment: When I'm pulling the AZ information, I pull it from the subnet that the Interface resides in. The abstractions as I see them are: EC2 Instances have Network Interfaces which reside in a Subnet which resides in an AZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Availability Zone** is an attribute of the Subnet.

Therefore, you can use:

```py
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

output = {}

for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    for iface in instance.network_interfaces:
        output[instance.id] = {
            'Instance ID': instance.id,
            'Subnet ID': iface.subnet_id,
            'AZ': iface.subnet.availability_zone
        }

print(output)
```

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks for your help!